# files modified when i was not home

Tags: windows-7, date-modified

I noticed some of my music files were modified (Windows 7, NTFS) when I wasn't home.  They have different MD5 checksums. I looked in the Event View to see if I could find anything about what might do it.  The antivirus programs don't check that drive.   I manually scanned the file with the antivirus program and it says it is not infected.

Is there anyway that you have it so the program/process name which causes the "date modified" date to change?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it that you're looking for? Regular file writes don't create an event. The MD5 hash of the audio files will be different if metadata was updated, cover art was embedded, etc.

Comment: How often do you check MD5 checksums for audio files on your own computer?   Was the checksum done on the entire directory structure, or are you doing checksums on individual files?   What other than the MD5 checksums leads you to believe that someone might have messed with your files?   Is there someone you live with that might possibily have any reason to do something like this?   Do you have cats?   I know my cat (who is actually sitting on my keyboard as I type this!) has renamed My Computer before, and seems to know how to open apps and then actually smash keys and enter information.

Comment: Thanks for the replie.  I just wanted to compare the checksum of a backup of the file with the newly modified.  Maybe there is something I can do with the Resource Monitor, but I haven't seen this happen before.    I just wish I could find out the program that did it.  It probably is nothing done from Malware.

Answer (score 0):

Some background thread could be altering your files. Are there any other programs active?

For example: Windows Media Player could run its volume flattener.